# Android onesignal notification text in HTML format

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

Hi I would like to send notifications with title and description. Except that the discription form is in html. there is a way to display it using:
Html.fromHtml () or same else

not like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Firebase to send notifications and in the app i use WebView like this
WebView .loadDataWithBaseURL("", "write html code here", "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
I hope it solve your problem. let me know if u need more help!